# Prevent escape key in dialog box from being passed to underlying window

Tags: javascript, dialog, event-handling

I have a listener for keyup which will unload my javascript slideshow if an escape key is pressed.

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", this.escapekeyfn, false);
```

However, within the slideshow is the option to print an image using `window.print()`- but if the user presses escape while in that dialog, it is passed down to my listener and the slideshow exits.

Any way to prevent this in pure js? I've tried to find any event properties which can help me determine where the escape came from. `originalTarget` looked promising, but once a dialog is called, the originalTarget is changed to BODY ever more.

**The Listeners**

The  escape key handling (the essential code for this)

```
slideshow.prototype.initslideshow = function(){
    _this = this
    ....
    this.escapekeyfn = function(e){ _this.escapekeycheck(e, _this)};
    window.addEventListener("keyup", this.escapekeyfn, false);        
    ....
}
```

The print button:

```
slideshow.prototype.printlink = function(){
    var _this = this;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    a.onclick = function(e){e.stopPropagation();window.print();return false};
    ....
}

slideshow.prototype.escapekeycheck = function(e, _this){
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        _this.ssclose(e);
    }
}
```

**The close function:**

```
slideshow.prototype.ssclose = function(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();

    // stop listening for escape key
    window.removeEventListener("keyup", this.escapekeyfn);      
    return false;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: @mplungjan I use e.stopPropagation() everywhere - before `window.print()` and in `this.escapekeyfn`. Is there more I can do?

Comment: @mplungjan Fair enough - I've attached the essential code for the key handling and processing. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Perhaps the event.target would be "body" if not in the print dialog

Comment: @mplungjan That is exactly true... the first time. After escaping from the print dialog, every future escape, whether from the dialog or not, shows "BODY" for the event.target (and event.originalTarget). I tried setting focus back to an anchor using `document.getElementById("anchor").focus();` without luck.

Comment: if you have a working solution - post an answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came across a way to solve this problem. I changed `keyup` to `keypress`

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", keypressFn, false);
```

For some reason, the `keypress` event is not sent to the `window` object whereas the `keyup` one is while the print dialog is open.